# for in loop statement return undefined values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Need some help with this piece of a code. I am able to produce the results I want with the code in **Working Code**, but when I implement this code on another sheet (which is the master code) it does not work. scratching my head trying to figure this out

Here is the shared google spreadsheet with both full codes. Go to script editor.
[Google Docs Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1adXbsUp2T0DroWhern1oU4oaKszO37X7spBKiImYC8Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

**EDIT#3 Submit section of None Working Code**

```
function submit(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissioSSKey).getActiveSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var projectname = e.parameter.projectname;
  var projectid = e.parameter.projectid;
  var projectmanager = e.parameter.projectmanager;
  var salesrep = e.parameter.salesrep;
  var duedate = e.parameter.duedate;
  var projectphase = e.parameter.projectphase;
  var disctype = e.parameter.disctype;
  var mediatype = e.parameter.mediatype;
  var encryptiontype = e.parameter.encryptiontype;
  var password = e.parameter.password;
  var quantity = e.parameter.quantity;
  var specialinstructions = e.parameter.specialinstructions;
  var update = "Colombo Save"; 
  
  //var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var uiData = [[
    projectname,
    projectid,
    projectmanager,
    salesrep,
    duedate,
    projectphase,
    disctype,
    mediatype,
    encryptiontype,
    password,
    quantity,
    specialinstructions,
    update
  ]];
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, uiData.length, uiData[0].length)
  .setValues(uiData);
  
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var result = {};
  var numMembers = parseInt(e.parameter.table_tag);
  result.members = [];
    
    for(var i=1; i<=numMembers; i++){
      var member = {};
      member.firstName = e.parameter['fName'+i];
      member.lastName = e.parameter['lName'+i];
      member.company = e.parameter['company'+i];
      member.address = e.parameter['address'+i];
      result.members.push(member);
     }
     
var htmlBody = 'Shipping Information: <br>'
  for(var a in result.members) {
    var member = result.members[a];
    var fname = member.firstName;
    var lname = member.lastName;
    var company = member.company;
    var address = member.address;    
    
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/New_York", "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss"); // Timestamp
  var activeSessionuser = Session.getActiveUser();//Session.getEffectiveUser(); Get the current user in the spreadsheet
  var emailAddress = 'test@email.com'; //Venue Colombo Team
  var subject = "**Test Email** DVD Request Submitted - **Test Email**"+ projectname +" - "+projectid+" - "+ projectmanager;
  /^var emailBody =*/
  var emailBody = 
  "<br><font color=\"Blue\"><b><h2>Request Submitted</h2></b></font>"
  +"<br/>Hi Venue Colombo Team,<br/>"
  +"<br/>The following data room(s) will need a disc creation. Please begin bulk save data room and create ISO to upload to the FTP site:<br/>"
  +"<br/><b>Project Name:</b> " + projectname
  +"<br/><b>Project ID:</b> " + projectid
  +"<br/><b>Project Manager:</b> " + projectmanager
  +"<br/><b>Sales:</b> " + salesrep
  +"<br/>" + htmlBody + 'Client Name: '+ fname + ' ' + lname +'<br>'+ 'Company Name: '+ company +'<br>' + 'Address: ' + address +'<br>'+'<br>'+
  +"<br/>"
  +"<br/><b>Phase:</b> " + projectphase
  +"<br/><b>Disc Type:</b> " + disctype
  +"<br/>"
  +"<br/><b>Encryption:</b> " + encryptiontype
  +"<br/><b>Password:</b> " + password
  +"<br/><b>Quantity:</b> " + quantity
  +"<br/>"
  +"<br/><b>Client Due Date:</b> " + duedate
  +"<br/>"
  +"<br/><font color=\"Red\"><b>Special Instructions:</b></font> " + "<br/>"+ specialinstructions
  
  +"<i><br/>&nbsp;<br/>This request was submitted by:</i> "
  +"<br/><font color=\"blue\">Name:</font> " + activeSessionuser
  +"<br/>Time Stamp: "  + timestamp
  +"<br/>"
  +"&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;&#8212;"
  + //Line divider code &#8212;
   "<br/>Venue Client Services"
  +"<br/>United States: "
  +"<br/>UK/International: "
  +"<br/>France: "
  +"<br/>Asia: ";
  
    htmlBody += 'Client Name: '+ fname + ' ' + lname +'<br>'+ 'Company Name: '+ company +'<br>' + 'Address: ' + address +'<br>'+'<br>';
  }
  var optAdvancedArgs = {name: "Venue Client Services", htmlBody: emailBody};
  //MailApp.sendEmail('fake@email.com', subject, '', optAdvancedArgs);
  Logger.log(htmlBody);
  Logger.log(emailBody);
  var html = app.createHTML('First Name: '+ fname + ' ' + lname +'<br>'+ 'Company Name: '+ company +'<br>' + 'Client Address: ' + address);
  app.add(html);
  //dvdForm();
return app;
 }
```

Here is the result on the Application

[image: UiApplication]

Here is the Logger logs

```
Logger.log(htmlBody);
Logger.log(emailBody);
```

[image: Logger.logs]

Comment: Here is the previous posthttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670782/google-script-for-loop-statement-return-undefined-values

Comment: ok. marked duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670782/google-script-for-loop-statement‌​-return-undefined-values .Please read the forum guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out what the issues was with "for loop statement return undefined values"

I did not add a `.addCallbackElement` to the panel containing the form fields.